# Why I am getting all elements in one line

Tags: xml

```html
<?php
// setting up PDO
include ('connectDB.php');
include ('auth.php');
$userID = $_SESSION['tblusers_id'];

// prepare all queries...
$favouritSongs = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblsaved_song WHERE userID = :userID");
$favouritSongs->bindParam(':userID', $userID);


// fetch all artists
$favouritSongs->execute();
$favouriteList=$favouritSongs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$x=new XMLWriter();
$x->openMemory();
$x->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$x->startElement('music');

foreach ($favouriteList as $element) {

 $x->startElement('songtitle');
 $x->text($element['songtitle']);
 $x->endElement();
    $x->startElement('link');
 $x->text($element['link']);
 $x->endElement();
    $x->startElement('genre');
 $x->text($element['genre']);
 $x->endElement();
    $x->startElement('releaseyear');
 $x->text($element['releaseyear']);
 $x->endElement();
    $x->startElement('datesaved');
    $x->text($element['datesaved']);
 

    // fetch all albums of this artist

    $x->endElement(); // artist
} // foreach $artists

$x->endElement(); // music
$x->endDocument();
$xml = $x->outputMemory();

// now save $xml to a file etc.
header("Content-type: text/xml");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="exported_playlist.xml"');
print_r ($xml);
?>
```

Hi, I am trying to export data from MySQL database and store them to XML file.

Everything works fine, the only problem I have is that all elements are in one line. How could I amend the code to get each element in new line.
Thank you.

Comment: MySQL is going to be reading it, not a human. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-set-indent.php

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation what I understood is, you are not able to indent the xml code

In-order to indent, you can do `$xml->setIndent(true);` after `$x->openMemory();` in you code.

Comment: That's perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can go with following snippet:

```
var val = prompt("enter number");
var New = val.split("");
var arr1 = [];
console.log(New);
for (i = New.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr1 += New[i];
} console.log(arr1);
```